# Jmeter script response not tally with RESTClient response

Tags: jmeter, rest-client

I am using JMeter to test the performance of rest API.
The problem is when I check the response of an API in the JMeter with the response of the rest client the response code doesn't look similar .
Jmeter response code contains null values for some key value pairs

Below is my JMeter response code for a rest API

```
{"isListException":false,"listMessage":null,"listSize":11,"page":1,"pageSize":0,"totalPages":4,"totalRecords":36,"users":[{"active":0,"address":null,"addressSize":0,"age":20,"analysisMessage":false,"androidVersion":null,"anniversayDate":null,"billingAddress":{"addId":0,"address1":"#908, gurunagar 4th block,mangalore","address2":null,"city":null,"country":null,"postBox":null,"state":null,"street":null,"zipCode":0},"callType":0,"SubScriptionId":0,"customerId":0,"customerUpdatedDate":null,"dateOfBirth":null,"deviceToken":null,"downloadDate":null,"downloadedDate":null,"emailId":null,"emailIdValid":false,"firstName":"manoj","fromDate":null,"gender":true,"generalMessage":false,"id":0,"iMEI":null,"iMEIValid":false,"internationalNumber":false,"isException":false,"knownBy":null,"lastName":null,"lastUpdatedDate":null,"loginId":null,"mainUser":true,"message":null,"mobile":null,"mobileOSPlatform":null,"osVersion":null,"password":null,"permissionString":null,"phoneNoValid":false,"primary":0,"productName":null,"randomImeiNumber":null,"randomSimSerialNumber":null,"reference":null,"serviceSubScriptionId":0,"simSerialNumber":null,"subuserId":0,"toDate":null,"uniquePhoneId":null,"userAddressList":[],"userCategory":0,"userCustomerId":0,"userGroup":0,"userId":3,"userType":null,"uuidStatus":false,"version":0,"viewsCount":0},{"active":0,"address":null,"addressSize":0,"age":22,"analysisMessage":false,"androidVersion":null,"anniversayDate":null,"billingAddress":{"addId":0,"address1":"nagar","address2":null,"city":null,"country":null,"postBox":null,"state":null,"street":null,"zipCode":0},"callType":0,"SubScriptionId":0,"customerId":0,"customerUpdatedDate":null,"dateOfBirth":null,"deviceToken":null,"downloadDate":null,"downloadedDate":null,"emailId":null,"emailIdValid":false,"firstName":"lakshmi","fromDate":null,"gender":false,"generalMessage":false,"id":0,"iMEI":null,"iMEIValid":false,"internationalNumber":false,"isException":false,"knownBy":null,"lastName":null,"lastUpdatedDate":null,"loginId":null,"mainUser":false,"message":null,"mobile":null,"mobileOSPlatform":null,"osVersion":null,"password":null,"permissionString":null,"phoneNoValid":false,"primary":0,"productName":null,"randomImeiNumber":null,"randomSimSerialNumber":null,"reference":null,"serviceRequestSubScriptionId":0,"simSerialNumber":null,"subuserId":1042,"toDate":null,"uniquePhoneId":null,"userAddressList":[],"userCategory":0,"userCustomerId":0,"userGroup":0,"userId":3,"userType":null,"uuidStatus":false,"version":0,"viewsCount":0},{"active":0,"address":null,"addressSize":0,"age":576,"analysisMessage":false,"androidVersion":null,"anniversayDate":null,"billingAddress":{"addId":0,"address1":"hhj","address2":null,"city":null,"country":null,"postBox":null,"state":null,"street":null,"zipCode":0},"callType":0,"SubScriptionId":0,"customerId":0,"customerUpdatedDate":null,"dateOfBirth":null,"deviceToken":null,"downloadDate":null,"downloadedDate":null,"emailId":null,"emailIdValid":false,"firstName":"eertr","fromDate":null,"gender":true,"generalMessage":false,"id":0,"iMEI":null,"iMEIValid":false,"internationalNumber":false,"isException":false,"knownBy":null,"lastName":null,"lastUpdatedDate":null,"loginId":null,"mainUser":false,"message":null,"mobile":null,"mobileOSPlatform":null,"osVersion":null,"password":null,"permissionString":null,"phoneNoValid":false,"primary":0,"productName":null,"randomImeiNumber":null,"randomSimSerialNumber":null,"reference":null,"serviceRequestSubScriptionId":0,"simSerialNumber":null,"subuserId":1036,"toDate":null,"uniquePhoneId":null,"userAddressList":[],"userCategory":0,"userCustomerId":0,"userGroup":0,"userId":3,"userType":null,"uuidStatus":false,"version":0,"viewsCount":0},{"active":0,"address":null,"addressSize":0,"age":232,"analysisMessage":false,"androidVersion":null,"anniversayDate":null,{"addId":0,"address1":"rajajinagar ","address2":null,"city":null,"country":null,"postBox":null,"state":null,"street":null,"zipCode":0},"callType":0,"SubScriptionId":0,"customerId":0,"customerUpdatedDate":null,"dateOfBirth":null,"deviceToken":null,"downloadDate":null,"downloadedDate":null,"emailId":null,"emailIdValid":false,"firstName":"Sam","fromDate":null,"gender":false,"generalMessage":false,"id":0,"iMEI":null,"iMEIValid":false,"internationalNumber":false,"isException":false,"knownBy":null,"lastName":null,"lastUpdatedDate":null,"loginId":null,"mainUser":false,"message":null,"mobile":null,"mobileOSPlatform":null,"osVersion":null,"password":null,"permissionString":null,"phoneNoValid":false,"primary":0,"productName":null,"randomImeiNumber":null,"randomSimSerialNumber":null,"reference":null,"serviceRequestSubScriptionId":0,"simSerialNumber":null,"subuserId":1021,"toDate":null,"uniquePhoneId":null,"userAddressList":[],"userCategory":0,"userCustomerId":0,"userGroup":0,"userId":3,"userType":null,"uuidStatus":false,"version":0,"viewsCount":0}]}
```

Below is response in RESTClient

```
<userList>
<isListException>false</isListException>
<listSize>11</listSize>
<page>1</page>
<pageSize>0</pageSize>
<totalPages>4</totalPages>
<totalRecords>36</totalRecords>
<users>
<id>0</id>
<isException>false</isException>
<active>0</active>
<addressSize>0</addressSize>
<age>20</age>
<analysisMessage>false</analysisMessage>
<billingAddress>
<addId>0</addId>
<address1>#908, gurunagar 4th block,mangalore</address1>
<zipCode>0</zipCode>
</billingAddress>
<callType>0</callType>
<SubScriptionId>0</SubScriptionId>
<customerId>0</customerId>
<emailIdValid>false</emailIdValid>
<firstName>manoj</firstName>
<gender>true</gender>
<generalMessage>false</generalMessage>
<IMEIValid>false</IMEIValid>
<internationalNumber>false</internationalNumber>
<mainUser>true</mainUser>
<phoneNoValid>false</phoneNoValid>
<primary>0</primary>
<serviceRequestSubScriptionId>0</serviceRequestSubScriptionId>
<subuserId>0</subuserId>
<userCategory>0</userCategory>
<userCustomerId>0</userCustomerId>
<userGroup>0</userGroup>
<userId>3</userId>
<uuidStatus>false</uuidStatus>
<version>0</version>
<viewsCount>0</viewsCount>
</users>
<users>
<id>0</id>
<isException>false</isException>
<active>0</active>
<addressSize>0</addressSize>
<age>22</age>
<analysisMessage>false</analysisMessage>
<billingAddress>
<addId>0</addId>
<address1>jayanagar</address1>
<zipCode>0</zipCode>
</billingAddress>
<callType>0</callType>
<SubScriptionId>0</SubScriptionId>
<customerId>0</customerId>
<emailIdValid>false</emailIdValid>
<firstName>lakshmi</firstName>
<gender>false</gender>
<generalMessage>false</generalMessage>
<IMEIValid>false</IMEIValid>
<internationalNumber>false</internationalNumber>
<mainUser>false</mainUser>
<phoneNoValid>false</phoneNoValid>
<primary>0</primary>
<serviceRequestSubScriptionId>0</serviceRequestSubScriptionId>
<subuserId>1042</subuserId>
<userCategory>0</userCategory>
<userCustomerId>0</userCustomerId>
<userGroup>0</userGroup>
<userId>3</userId>
<uuidStatus>false</uuidStatus>
<version>0</version>
<viewsCount>0</viewsCount>
</users>
<users>
<id>0</id>
<isException>false</isException>
<active>0</active>
<addressSize>0</addressSize>
<age>576</age>
<analysisMessage>false</analysisMessage>
<billingAddress>
<addId>0</addId>
<address1>hhj</address1>
<zipCode>0</zipCode>
</billingAddress>
<callType>0</callType>
<SubScriptionId>0</SubScriptionId>
<customerId>0</customerId>
<emailIdValid>false</emailIdValid>
<firstName>eertr</firstName>
<gender>true</gender>
<generalMessage>false</generalMessage>
<IMEIValid>false</IMEIValid>
<internationalNumber>false</internationalNumber>
<mainUser>false</mainUser>
<phoneNoValid>false</phoneNoValid>
<primary>0</primary>
<serviceRequestSubScriptionId>0</serviceRequestSubScriptionId>
<subuserId>1036</subuserId>
<userCategory>0</userCategory>
<userCustomerId>0</userCustomerId>
<userGroup>0</userGroup>
<userId>3</userId>
<uuidStatus>false</uuidStatus>
<version>0</version>
<viewsCount>0</viewsCount>
</users>
<users>
<id>0</id>
<isException>false</isException>
<active>0</active>
<addressSize>0</addressSize>
<age>232</age>
<analysisMessage>false</analysisMessage>
<billingAddress>
<addId>0</addId>
<address1>vdfgfg</address1>
<zipCode>0</zipCode>
</billingAddress>
<callType>0</callType>
<SubScriptionId>0</SubScriptionId>
<customerId>0</customerId>
<emailIdValid>false</emailIdValid>
<firstName>bbbbb</firstName>
<gender>true</gender>
<generalMessage>false</generalMessage>
<IMEIValid>false</IMEIValid>
<internationalNumber>false</internationalNumber>
<mainUser>false</mainUser>
<phoneNoValid>false</phoneNoValid>
<primary>0</primary>
<serviceRequestSubScriptionId>0</serviceRequestSubScriptionId>
<subuserId>1035</subuserId>
<userCategory>0</userCategory>
<userCustomerId>0</userCustomerId>
<userGroup>0</userGroup>
<userId>3</userId>
<uuidStatus>false</uuidStatus>
<version>0</version>
<viewsCount>0</viewsCount>
</users>
<users>
<id>0</id>
<isException>false</isException>
<active>0</active>
<addressSize>0</addressSize>
<age>243</age>
<analysisMessage>false</analysisMessage>
<billingAddress>
<addId>0</addId>
<address1>asdf</address1>
<zipCode>0</zipCode>
</billingAddress>
<callType>0</callType>
<SubScriptionId>0</SubScriptionId>
<customerId>0</customerId>
<emailIdValid>false</emailIdValid>
<firstName>ccc</firstName>
<gender>true</gender>
<generalMessage>false</generalMessage>
<IMEIValid>false</IMEIValid>
<internationalNumber>false</internationalNumber>
<mainUser>false</mainUser>
<phoneNoValid>false</phoneNoValid>
<primary>0</primary>
<serviceRequestSubScriptionId>0</serviceRequestSubScriptionId>
<subuserId>1034</subuserId>
<userCategory>0</userCategory>
<userCustomerId>0</userCustomerId>
<userGroup>0</userGroup>
<userId>3</userId>
<uuidStatus>false</uuidStatus>
<version>0</version>
<viewsCount>0</viewsCount>
</users>
<users>
<id>0</id>
<isException>false</isException>
<active>0</active>
<addressSize>0</addressSize>
<age>334</age>
<analysisMessage>false</analysisMessage>
<billingAddress>
<addId>0</addId>
<address1>fgtgfgf</address1>
<zipCode>0</zipCode>
</billingAddress>
<callType>0</callType>
<SubScriptionId>0</SubScriptionId>
<customerId>0</customerId>
<emailIdValid>false</emailIdValid>
<firstName>rthttx</firstName>
<gender>true</gender>
<generalMessage>false</generalMessage>
<IMEIValid>false</IMEIValid>
<internationalNumber>false</internationalNumber>
<mainUser>false</mainUser>
<phoneNoValid>false</phoneNoValid>
<primary>0</primary>
<serviceRequestSubScriptionId>0</serviceRequestSubScriptionId>
<subuserId>1033</subuserId>
<userCategory>0</userCategory>
<userCustomerId>0</userCustomerId>
<userGroup>0</userGroup>
<userId>3</userId>
<uuidStatus>false</uuidStatus>
<version>0</version>
<viewsCount>0</viewsCount>
</users>
<users>
<id>0</id>
<isException>false</isException>
<active>0</active>
<addressSize>0</addressSize>
<age>121</age>
<analysisMessage>false</analysisMessage>
<billingAddress>
<addId>0</addId>
<address1>jayanagar</address1>
<zipCode>0</zipCode>
</billingAddress>
<callType>0</callType>
<SubScriptionId>0</SubScriptionId>
<customerId>0</customerId>
<emailIdValid>false</emailIdValid>
<firstName>bvbi</firstName>
<gender>true</gender>
<generalMessage>false</generalMessage>
<IMEIValid>false</IMEIValid>
<internationalNumber>false</internationalNumber>
<mainUser>false</mainUser>
<phoneNoValid>false</phoneNoValid>
<primary>0</primary>
<serviceRequestSubScriptionId>0</serviceRequestSubScriptionId>
<subuserId>1030</subuserId>
<userCategory>0</userCategory>
<userCustomerId>0</userCustomerId>
<userGroup>0</userGroup>
<userId>3</userId>
<uuidStatus>false</uuidStatus>
<version>0</version>
<viewsCount>0</viewsCount>
</users>
<users>
<id>0</id>
<isException>false</isException>
<active>0</active>
<addressSize>0</addressSize>
<age>445</age>
<analysisMessage>false</analysisMessage>
<billingAddress>
<addId>0</addId>
<address1>wefrftghyu</address1>
<zipCode>0</zipCode>
</billingAddress>
<callType>0</callType>
<SubScriptionId>0</SubScriptionId>
<customerId>0</customerId>
<emailIdValid>false</emailIdValid>
<firstName>name</firstName>
<gender>true</gender>
<generalMessage>false</generalMessage>
<IMEIValid>false</IMEIValid>
<internationalNumber>false</internationalNumber>
<mainUser>false</mainUser>
<phoneNoValid>false</phoneNoValid>
<primary>0</primary>
<serviceRequestSubScriptionId>0</serviceRequestSubScriptionId>
<subuserId>1028</subuserId>
<userCategory>0</userCategory>
<userCustomerId>0</userCustomerId>
<userGroup>0</userGroup>
<userId>3</userId>
<uuidStatus>false</uuidStatus>
<version>0</version>
<viewsCount>0</viewsCount>
</users>
<users>
<id>0</id>
<isException>false</isException>
<active>0</active>
<addressSize>0</addressSize>
<age>24</age>
<analysisMessage>false</analysisMessage>
<billingAddress>
<addId>0</addId>
<address1>bum</address1>
<zipCode>0</zipCode>
</billingAddress>
<callType>0</callType>
<SubScriptionId>0</SubScriptionId>
<customerId>0</customerId>
<emailIdValid>false</emailIdValid>
<firstName>kishore </firstName>
<gender>false</gender>
<generalMessage>false</generalMessage>
<IMEIValid>false</IMEIValid>
<internationalNumber>false</internationalNumber>
<mainUser>false</mainUser>
<phoneNoValid>false</phoneNoValid>
<primary>0</primary>
<serviceRequestSubScriptionId>0</serviceRequestSubScriptionId>
<subuserId>1023</subuserId>
<userCategory>0</userCategory>
<userCustomerId>0</userCustomerId>
<userGroup>0</userGroup>
<userId>3</userId>
<uuidStatus>false</uuidStatus>
<version>0</version>
<viewsCount>0</viewsCount>
</users>
<users>
<id>0</id>
<isException>false</isException>
<active>0</active>
<addressSize>0</addressSize>
<age>28</age>
<analysisMessage>false</analysisMessage>
<billingAddress>
<addId>0</addId>
<address1>Jayanagar </address1>
<zipCode>0</zipCode>
</billingAddress>
<callType>0</callType>
<SubScriptionId>0</SubScriptionId>
<customerId>0</customerId>
<emailIdValid>false</emailIdValid>
<firstName>Mithun</firstName>
<gender>false</gender>
<generalMessage>false</generalMessage>
<IMEIValid>false</IMEIValid>
<internationalNumber>false</internationalNumber>
<mainUser>false</mainUser>
<phoneNoValid>false</phoneNoValid>
<primary>0</primary>
<serviceRequestSubScriptionId>0</serviceRequestSubScriptionId>
<subuserId>1022</subuserId>
<userCategory>0</userCategory>
<userCustomerId>0</userCustomerId>
<userGroup>0</userGroup>
<userId>3</userId>
<uuidStatus>false</uuidStatus>
<version>0</version>
<viewsCount>0</viewsCount>
</users>
<users>
<id>0</id>
<isException>false</isException>
<active>0</active>
<addressSize>0</addressSize>
<age>23</age>
<analysisMessage>false</analysisMessage>
<billingAddress>
<addId>0</addId>
<address1>rajajinagar </address1>
<zipCode>0</zipCode>
</billingAddress>
<callType>0</callType>
<SubScriptionId>0</SubScriptionId>
<customerId>0</customerId>
<emailIdValid>false</emailIdValid>
<firstName>Sam</firstName>
<gender>false</gender>
<generalMessage>false</generalMessage>
<IMEIValid>false</IMEIValid>
<internationalNumber>false</internationalNumber>
<mainUser>false</mainUser>
<phoneNoValid>false</phoneNoValid>
<primary>0</primary>
<serviceRequestSubScriptionId>0</serviceRequestSubScriptionId>
<subuserId>1021</subuserId>
<userCategory>0</userCategory>
<userCustomerId>0</userCustomerId>
<userGroup>0</userGroup>
<userId>3</userId>
<uuidStatus>false</uuidStatus>
<version>0</version>
<viewsCount>0</viewsCount>
</users>
</userList>
```

Comment: Can you please provide HTTP request headers. There is chance that the header 'Accept' might set as JSON in Jmeter and XML in your rest client